# How do I share variables with another class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, scope, class-design

I have two classes, Player and Controller.  The Controller has the main game loop, and contains a Player.  It also stores the world map. The Controller class passes user input to the player by calling various methods of the Player class, such as moveForward().  I am now implementing collision detection, and to do so, I need a way for the Player class to see the world map, but this is in the Controller class in which the Player class is.

In other words:

```
struct Controller {
    int worldMap[16][16][16];
    Player p;
    ...
}

struct Player {
    movePlayer() {
        #How do I check world map here?
    }
}
```

Comment: I would create a worldMap class and pass that around instead of the array directly, as you might decide on a different data structure in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data that `movePlayer()` needs as a reference parameter:

```
void movePlayer(const int (&map)[16][16][16]) { ... }
```

Passing the whole `Controller` object would be bad if `movePlayer()` only needs access to `worldMap`.

---

Alternatively, you could store a pointer to the current map in the `Player` object itself:

```
struct Player {
    // ...

private:
    int* Location;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity let us assume that all you want to do is call a simple function (checking the other member works the same way but leads to more complicated examples):

```
void move(Player&);
```

You can only access non-`static` members if you have an object at hand. If you do, it is as simple as:

```
struct Player {
    void movePlayer(Controller& controller) {
        move(controller.p);
    }
};
```

Note the `;` following the `struct` declaration, it is required.

If you have `static` members on the other hand they are valid for the whole class and thus don't even need an object:

```
struct Player {
    void movePlayer();
};

struct Controller {
    static Player p;
};

void Player::movePlayer() {
    move(Controller::p);
}
```

Note the order in which the declarations appear: To declare a variable of type `Player`, you need to first declare the `struct Player`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are propably accessing the controller a lot, you can pass in a pointer to the `Player` and there you assign it to a member.

```
struct Controller {
    int worldMap[16][16][16];
    Player p;
    ...

    Controller() {
        p.setController( this );
    }
};

struct Player {
    Controller* mController;
    movePlayer() {

        mController->...

    }
    setController( Controller* controller ) {
        mController = controller;
    }
};
```

If you need access to it at a low interval, you can pass a reference into the function.

```
    Player::movePlayer( Controller* controller ) {

        mController->...

    }
```